# Windows Phone 8 Record sound from microphone C#

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8

I am pretty new to windows phone, and I would like to create simple app that can record sound from mic, and save it.

I already have searched for some classes that are able to record, but I didn't find anything I can understand. I have found MediaCapture class, but I cant find any tutorial or guide how to set up recording. I also found using Xna Framework Audio, but I have read that it is no longer developing and it is becoming unsupported on win phones.

Can you guys point me towards direction I can accomplish this sound recording ?
Windows phone 8, C#, Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, I do. Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Comment: This is a pretty good tutorial with example I used a while ago http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/175122/Making-a-Voice-Recorder-on-Windows-Phone

Answer (score 1):

So after a while, I have found this tutorial, I haven't tested it yet, but it seems it is what I was looking for. Really clean nice tutorial, it is using MediaCapture class. [Link](http://books.google.sk/books?id=QsukAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA358&lpg=PA358&dq=mediacapture%20audio%20c%23&source=bl&ots=aNdFVMwGFH&sig=TIdLgGW6ZV5uXqQ_3CHl6j51en8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Pd8EVMzBEMiUO5WwgNAC&ved=0CGIQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=mediacapture%20audio%20c%23&f=false)